# PlayN JBox2D Y velocity increases but collision happens

Tags: java, box2d, collision, playn, jbox2d

So i'm seeing a really strange problem.

using the PlayN peas demo from the showcase i put together a simple app - i have a dynamic entity dropping onto a static entity and i cannot figure out why it isn't bouncing.

After doing some printouts i find that the collision is happening - the y position stays the same but the y velocity just keeps increasing

here's my update code in the dynamic entity

```
  @Override
  public void paint(float alpha) {
    float x = (body.getPosition().x * alpha) + (previousX * (1f - alpha));
    float y = (body.getPosition().y * alpha) + (previousY * (1f - alpha));
    float w = (body.getAngle() * alpha) + (previousRotationAngle * (1f - alpha));
    if (body.m_type == BodyType.DYNAMIC) {
      System.out.println("body x = " + body.getPosition().x + ", y = " + body.getPosition().y);
      System.out.println("velocity x = " + body.m_linearVelocity.x + ", y = "
      + body.m_linearVelocity.y);
    }
    imageLayer.setTranslation(x, y);
    imageLayer.setRotation(w);
  }

  @Override
  public void update(float delta) {
    previousX = body.getPosition().x;
    previousY = body.getPosition().y;
    previousRotationAngle = body.getAngle();
  }
```

here's the printout - as you can see the velocity keeps going up but the y position stays the same right at 8.46

```
  [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 0.5199691
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 1.2983631
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 0.79601336
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 2.562787
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 0.8908453
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 2.8736944
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 0.99586946
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 3.18255
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 0.99586946
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 3.18255
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 1.1110185
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 3.489367
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 1.2362258
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 3.794159
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 1.2362258
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 3.794159
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 1.3714248
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 4.096939
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 1.5165496
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 4.3977213
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 1.6715348
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 4.696518
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 1.6715348
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 4.696518
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 1.8363149
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 4.993343
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 2.0108259
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 5.2882085
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 2.195003
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 5.581128
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 2.388783
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 5.8721147
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 2.388783
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 5.8721147
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 2.5921018
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 6.1611805
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 2.5921018
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 6.1611805
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 2.804897
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 6.4483385
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 3.0271058
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 6.733601
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 3.0271058
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 6.733601
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 3.2586663
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 7.016981
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 3.4995165
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 7.298491
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 3.4995165
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 7.298491
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 3.7495952
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 7.5781426
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 4.0088415
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 7.8559484
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 4.277195
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 8.131921
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 4.5545955
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 8.406072
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 4.5545955
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 8.406072
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 4.840983
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 8.678413
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 4.840983
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 8.678413
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 5.1362987
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 8.948957
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 5.440483
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 9.217716
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 5.440483
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 9.217716
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 5.753478
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 9.484701
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 6.0752254
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 9.749924
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 6.0752254
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 9.749924
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 6.4056673
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 10.013396
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 6.7447467
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 10.275129
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 7.0924063
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 10.535135
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 7.0924063
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 10.535135
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 7.4485893
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 10.793425
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 7.8132396
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 11.05001
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 7.8132396
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 11.05001
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 8.186301
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 11.304901
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 8.465522
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 11.55811
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 8.465522
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 11.55811
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 8.465522
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 11.8096485
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 8.465522
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 12.059526
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 8.465522
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 12.059526
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 8.465522
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 12.307755
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 8.465522
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 12.554346
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 8.465522
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 12.554346
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 8.465522
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 12.799309
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 8.465522
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 13.042655
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 8.465522
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 13.042655
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 8.465522
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 13.284395
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 8.465522
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 13.52454
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 8.465522
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 13.7631
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 8.465522
 [java] velocity x = 0.0, y = 13.7631
 [java] body x = 17.024979, y = 8.465522
```

and here's an image - the flower was my test dynamic entity - it clearly stopped on the brick but i can't figure out why the velocity is just continuing to go up

[image]

---

i don't know what other code would be helpful here - i have a setup that is virtually identical to the Peas Demo from the showcase - to the point where I've deleted things from the Showcase demo and can't recreate the problem in that.

I am 100% at a loss here and since it's a physics problem it's kind of hindering all my progress.  The peas demo completely works

Any help would be greatly appreciated - i have tried for 4 hours now trying all the things i can think of and nothing is working

---

edit added main world class (this is definitely pretty ugly - please don't judge me)

```
public class LevelWorld implements ContactListener, Paintable, Updatable, Destroyable {

  private static final float PHYSICS_UNITS_PER_PIXEL = PhysicsScale.PHYSICS_UNITS_PER_PIXEL
  .getScaleFactor();

  private final playn.core.GroupLayer worldLayer;

  private final Context context;
  private final World world;
  private final float frameRate;

  private final List<playn.core.GroupLayer> groupLayers;
  private final List<Entity> entities;
  private final Stack<Contact> contacts;
  private final Map<Body, PhysicsEntity> bodies;

  public LevelWorld(Level level, Context context) {
    worldLayer = graphics().createGroupLayer();
    worldLayer.setScale(1.F / PHYSICS_UNITS_PER_PIXEL);
    this.context = context;
    final Integer fps = (Integer) context.get(FPS);
    this.frameRate = 1.F / fps.floatValue();
    final Vec2 gravity = new Vec2(0.F, 10.0F);
    world = new World(gravity, true);
    world.setWarmStarting(true);
    world.setAutoClearForces(true);
    groupLayers = new ArrayList<playn.core.GroupLayer>();
    entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
    contacts = new Stack<Contact>();
    bodies = new HashMap<Body, PhysicsEntity>();
    for (final GroupLayer groupLayer : level) {
      final playn.core.GroupLayer gl = graphics().createGroupLayer();
      gl.setDepth(groupLayer.getDepth());
      gl.setScale(groupLayer.getScaleFactor());
      groupLayers.add(gl);
      for (final Entity entity : groupLayer.getEntities()) {
        if (entity instanceof PhysicsEntity) {
          final FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
          final BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
          if (PhysicsType.DYNAMIC.equals(entity.getEntityMetadata().getPhysicsType())) {
            bodyDef.type = BodyType.DYNAMIC;
          } else if (PhysicsType.STATIC.equals(entity.getEntityMetadata().getPhysicsType())) {
            bodyDef.type = BodyType.STATIC;
          }
          final Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
          fixtureDef.shape = entity.getEntityMetadata().getShape();
          fixtureDef.density = 0.4f;
          fixtureDef.friction = 0.1f;
          fixtureDef.restitution = 0.5f;
          body.setLinearDamping(0.2f);
          body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
          body.setTransform(new Vec2(entity.getPosition().x, entity.getPosition().y),
          entity.getRotationAngle());
          ((PhysicsEntity) entity).setBody(body);
          bodies.put(body, (PhysicsEntity) entity);
        }
        gl.add(entity.getImageLayer());
      }
      entities.addAll(groupLayer.getEntities());
      worldLayer.add(gl);
    }
    graphics().rootLayer().add(worldLayer);
    world.setContactListener(this); // kinda sketchy
  }

  @Override
  public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
    System.out.println("BEGIN CONTACT HAPPENED");
    contacts.push(contact);
  }

  @Override
  public void endContact(Contact contact) {

  }

  @Override
  public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {

  }

  @Override
  public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {

  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {
    worldLayer.destroy();
  }

  @Override
  public void update(float delta) {
    // worldLayer.setOrigin(worldLayer.originX() + (delta / 250.F),
    // worldLayer.originY());
    for (final Entity entity : entities) {
      entity.update(delta);
    }
    world.step(0.033F, 10, 10);
    // processContacts();
  }

  @Override
  public void paint(float alpha) {
    for (final Entity entity : entities) {
      entity.paint(alpha);
    }
  }

  private void processContacts() {
    while (!contacts.isEmpty()) {
      final Contact contact = contacts.pop();
      final PhysicsEntity a = bodies.get(contact.m_fixtureA.m_body);
      final PhysicsEntity b = bodies.get(contact.m_fixtureB.m_body);

      if (a != null && b != null) {
        if (a instanceof PhysicsEntity.IsContactListener) {
          ((PhysicsEntity.IsContactListener) a).contact(b);
        }
        if (b instanceof PhysicsEntity.IsContactListener) {
          ((PhysicsEntity.IsContactListener) b).contact(a);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The collision handler is yours? If so, can we see it?

Comment: To tell you the truth like I said I modeled everything off of the Peas demo - they have a processContacts method in the PeaWorld class - I found commenting this out that the entities still bounce so right now I honestly don't think I have a collision handler - That being said I'll edit the post and add my World class

Comment: Perhaps you're supposed to implement a collision handler for custom objects.

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody runs into this - After a whole day and a half of trying to figure this out and creating a separate simple project dropping 1 dynamic entity onto a static entity and seeing it do the same thing.

If you see this happen where the Entity stops moving but the velocity keeps increasing - the Collision Shape you put in is BACKWARDS - i had 4 vertices being put into the shape in order of 0,1,2,3 - had I put them in as 3,2,1,0 it would have worked fine. I suppose if you hit this same type of problem try reversing the order your creating your shape and see if the collision works.

Comment: Or reverse your collision test.  Thats the big thing with insideness, you have to make sure the edges are oriented correctly, or you have to use a test that doesn't depend on it, which may be slower.

Comment: It's helpful to use Box2D's debug draw feature to see exactly what the physics engine is seeing. Chances are the polygon would not look right in debug draw which would tip you off straight away.